# Search within a big vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have following vectors:

```
std::vector<A*> vec;
std::vector<std::pair<A*, A*>> vec_pair;
```

vec_pair size is much more than vec size. I would like to find a pair within vec_pair which both members are inside vec.

contents of the `vec_pair` are constant. However after each iteration the contents of the `vec` will change and I would like to do the test again.

I know I can do a for loop and do the check. However considering **size difference** and **recurrence of the job**, I am looking for a smart and efficient way to do it.

Comment: Can you sort both vector ?

Comment: Is this a one-time job, or do you plan to maintain a structure supporting certain request types? E.g. insert, remove, search.

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry I just wanted to simplify the question, that's why I put "int". Actually No I can not sort the objects.

Comment: @Mikhail Multiple time job.

Comment: Multiple time job with which requests? Will content of your vectors modify? Can you afford to allocate additional memory? You should carefully describe your scenario in the question if you want a good answer.

Comment: For me it is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm sure if actual problem is explained, it will turn out that data should be organized in different meaner.

Comment: @H'H: Note: `A*` could be compared (as your previous `int*`), it is independent of the fact that your vector are read-only or not.

Comment: Just @MarekR says: If you tell us how and why `vec_pair` gets changed, we (and you) would probably be able to figure out something better to do what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not going to change content of `vec`, create an `std::unordered_set<A*>` with the same content and search for occurrences there. Searching in an `unordered_set` is approximately O(1), so this would be a simple win.

The easiest and the most efficient way to construct an `unordered_set` from a `vector` is to use the constructor taking two iterators:

```
unordered_set<A*> us(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: Stating that search in an `unordered_set` is O(1) without stating the complexity of constructing / populating the `unordered_set` seems a little disingenuous.

Comment: OP did not say how many search queries he wants to process comparing to the size of `vec`. In fact, he did not provide enough information to make a good complexity analysis. So I think the quality of the answer matches the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2):

> `vec_pair` size is much more than `vec` size.

This should act as **a clue** to you to use `std::map`.
Put all the elements of vector `vec` inside a map : `myMap[vec[i]] = 1;`
Then go through each pair in `vec_pair`, and do

```
if (myMap.find(vec_pair[i].first != myMap.end()) && 
    myMap.find(vec_pair[i].second != myMap.end()) ) 
{
    return FOUND; 
}
else 
    return NOT_FOUND;`
```

As commented by Gates, use `unordered_map` for faster operations.

Comment: Note, since OP is using C++11 he should really be using `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `unordered_set` (you don't really need a `map`) which allows `O(1)` *search* and *insert*.

1) From vec you build an `unordered_set<A*> S;`

2) For each pair in `vec_pair` you can check if both elements are present in `S`

Something like the following will do the job in average `O(vec_pair.size())`

```
std::vector<A*> vec;
std::vector<std::pair<A*, A*>> vec_pair;


unordered_set<A*> S;
for(auto a: vec)
    S.insert(a);

for(auto p : vec_pair){
    if(s.find(p.first)!=S.end() && 
        s.find(p.second)!=S.end())
    {
        //PAIR GOOD
    }else{
        //THIS PAIR IS NOT GOOD
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to implement hash of `A` to have `std::unortdered_set<A*>`. And you should not have loop with `S.insert`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know yours exactly requirements but, if the order of element in `vec_pair` isn't important, I suppose you can substitute it with a `std::multimap` or, I suppose better, a `std::unordered_multimap`.

I mean (using a type `A` equal to `int` as example) that instead

```
   using A = int;

   std::vector<std::pair<A, A>> const vec_pair
    { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4},
      {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4},
      {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4},
      {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4} };
```

you can use

```
   std::unordered_multimap<A, A> const cM
    { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4},
      {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4},
      {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4},
      {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4} };
```

If you need that `vec_pair` is a vector of pairs, using the fact that `vec_pair` is constant (I understand correctly?) you can contruct a constant unordered multimap.

The advantage of this solution is that if you find that a key of the map isn't in `vec`, you can avoid the test for all the values with the same key.

More: if construct a `set` (or, better, an `unordered_set`) starting from `vec` (that is little, if I understand correctly, you can check the pairs as follows

```
   for ( auto ci = cM.cbegin() ; ci != cM.cend() ; )
    {
      auto val = ci->first;
      auto cnt = cM.count(val);

      if ( s.end() == s.find(val) )
       {
         for ( auto i = 0U ; i < cnt ; ++i )
            ++ci;
       }
      else for ( auto i = 0U ; i < cnt ; ++i, ++ci ) 
         if ( s.end() != s.find(ci->second) )
            std::cout << "- good for <" << val << ", " << ci->second
               << '>' << std::endl;
    }
```

I know: isn't an elegant solution.

Another way is to use a combination of map and set (unorderd, better) and instead of

```
   std::vector<std::pair<A, A>> const vec_pair
    { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4},
      {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4},
      {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4},
      {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4} };
```

use (or construct)

```
   std::unordered_map<A, std::unordered_set<A>> const cM
    { {1, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {2, {1, 2, 3, 4}},
      {3, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {4, {1, 2, 3, 4}} };
```

In this case, the search part is more elegant (IMHO)

```
   for ( auto const & p : cM2 )
      if ( s.end() != s.find(p.first) )
         for ( auto const & sec : p.second )
            if ( s.end() != s.find(sec) )
            std::cout << "- good for <" << p.first << ", " << sec
               << '>' << std::endl;
```

The following is a full compilable example for both solutions

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>

int main()
 {
   using A = int;

   std::unordered_multimap<A, A> const cM
    { {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4},
      {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4},
      {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4},
      {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4} };

   std::unordered_set<A> s { 4, 3 };

   for ( auto ci = cM.cbegin() ; ci != cM.cend() ; )
    {
      auto val = ci->first;
      auto cnt = cM.count(val);

      if ( s.end() == s.find(val) )
       {
         for ( auto i = 0U ; i < cnt ; ++i )
            ++ci;
       }
      else for ( auto i = 0U ; i < cnt ; ++i, ++ci ) 
         if ( s.end() != s.find(ci->second) )
            std::cout << "- good for <" << val << ", " << ci->second
               << '>' << std::endl;
    }

   std::unordered_map<A, std::unordered_set<A>> const cM2
    { {1, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {2, {1, 2, 3, 4}},
      {3, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {4, {1, 2, 3, 4}} };

   for ( auto const & p : cM2 )
      if ( s.end() != s.find(p.first) )
         for ( auto const & sec : p.second )
            if ( s.end() != s.find(sec) )
            std::cout << "- good for <" << p.first << ", " << sec
               << '>' << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How much smaller is vec than vec_pair? Is the square of the size of vec still much smaller than the size of vec_pair? If so, you make an unordered_set out of vec_pair, and then search it for every possible pair generated from two things from vec.

Why can't you sort the two containers? Can you make a sorted copy of each? If so, take a pointer to the start of both lists, and increment both looking for matches. You would still be O(size of vec_pair) but your constant would be really small -- often just a single pointer comparison.